# Google Analytics search and replace filter takes out just the first found match

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to use google analytics search and replace filter just to remove some ids from the url.

Not sure why, but it just replaces the first found entry.
My url is something like **/path/[objectid]/another-path/[objectid]** and I need it transformed to **/path/another-path**, but after applying my filter will be **/path/another-path/[objectid]**.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement seems to be performed on only one occurrence (although the regex is correct), however you can **create another identical filter** and apply that to the View as well, in this way the second occurrence will also be replaced.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing currently just as a quick fix. I was wondering if there is any better solution for this. Many thanks for your answer.